# Grafana bar chart axis label grouping

Tags: bar-chart, grafana

currently having following bar chart in a grafana dashboard:
[image]

I would like to have a axis label grouping based on a different data column:
[image]

The data looks like the following:

[image]

Is there a way to configure the grafana bar chart to group the labels?

Answer (score 3):

Grafana's [Bar chart](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/bar-chart/) doesn't support multilevel axis.

Closest thing that can be imagined to what is described, is if you can "transpose" your data into the following format:

|  | row1_1 | row1_2 | row2_1 | row2_2 | row3_1 | row3_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 8 | 2 |
| Group2 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 0 |
| Group3 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 11 | 1 |
| Group4 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 |  |  |

Result will look something like this:
[image]